# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "sich hervorheben" und "sich hervortun"

Tags: expression, difference

Den Ausdruck "sich hervorheben" kenne ich schon, doch nun bin ich in einem Text auf "sich hervortun" gestossen. Genau genommen:

> "Das ganze Volk schaut auf ihn. Er hält sich immer so zurück und **tut sich nie hervor**"

Anhand des Kontexts scheint es mir, dass die Formulierung "hebt sich nie hervor" dieselbe Bedeutung hätte.

Verhält es sich so, oder gibt es irgendeinen feinen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Ausdrücken?

Comment: Was sagen die besseren Wörterbücher?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das Verb **hervorheben** wird nur sehr selten reflexiv benutzt. Man müsste sich ja an den eigenen Haaren hochziehen wie dereinst Lügenbold Münchhausen.

Genau dafür gibt es das Verb **sich hervortun**, das nur höchst selten *nicht* reflexiv verwendet wird. Es beschreibt den Drang nach vorne und im übertragenen Sinne eben, sich auffällig zu machen.

Answer (score 3):

**Sich hervorheben** ist eher passiv und die Hervorhebung wird entweder durch bestimmte Eigenschaften erreicht oder durch aktives Verhalten, dass nicht unbedingt die eigene Hervorhebung als Ziel hat. Die Beurteilung kommt dann auch meistens von einer eher objektiven Seite.

**Sich hervortun** ist dagegen eher aktiv und in der Regel mit dem Ziel sich auszuzeichnen.